# not able to split string using regex in groovy

Tags: groovy

iam not able to split string using regex
the following code iam using

```
String[] splitedEmail=email.split(/\\n\;\,\s/);
```

it's not splitting it's giving the same

Comment: Can you give an example value for `email`?

Comment: email="djdsfjdfbdj@gmail.com,fjgjfgfdjgifd@nkfvdj.com"

Comment: Right, so my answer should work?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to wrap it in a character class `[]`:

```
String[] splitedEmail = email.split( /[\n;,\s]/ )
```

Answer (score -1):

**Groovy Split() with Regular Expression**

Groovy String's split() method can also take a regular expression as a delimiter. Here are some examples:

Split by a single digit:

```
def sampleText = "A1B23C456D"
println sampleText.split(/\d/)
```

Since extra occurance of delimiter will yield empty Strings, the code will render:

```
[A, B, , C, , , D]
```

Split by 2 digits:

```
def sampleText = "A1B23C456D"
println sampleText.split(/\d\d/)
```

Since 23 and 45 are the only consecutive two digits, we will have the result:

```
[A1B, C, 6D]
```

Split by any number of digits:

```
def sampleText = "A1B23C456D"
println sampleText.split(/\d+/)
```

Will split the String with any length of digit sequence, hence the expected output:

```
[A, B, C, D]
```

More details please refer [here](http://grails.asia/groovy-split).